# Can charmed foes be considered "allies"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, charmed

I'm researching specifically the [Arcana Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#ArcanaDomain) feature, Spell Breaker (SCAG, p. 126):

> Starting at 6th level, when you restore hit points to an ally with a spell of 1st level or higher, you can also end one spell of your choice on that creature. The level of the spell you end must be equal to or lower than the level of the spell slot you use to cast the healing spell.

**If I charm an enemy and then cast a healing spell on them, would I be able to remove a beneficial spell on them (like [*crown of stars*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/crown-of-stars) or [*stoneskin*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/stoneskin))?**

There may be a circumstance where I didn't prepare [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) or have a level 3 spell slot to use for it, so I'd like to know what my options are.

If a charmed enemy is considered an ally, please include whether that extends to enemies charmed not by you, but by your allies as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Not automatically, but you have advantage on persuading them otherwise

The [charmed condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Charmed) states merely two effects:

> - A charmed creature can't attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects.
> - The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature.

So it guarantees they won't attack you, and makes them much more receptive to your attempts to interact with them, but it doesn't guarantee that they automatically consider you an ally and will willingly submit to magical effects. It also has no effect on the subject's interaction with other creatures, such as your other allies - being "charmed" only affects how the charmer and charmee can interact.

However, the spell [Charm Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person) also clarifies that:

> The charmed creature regards you as a friendly acquaintance.

This seems much closer to being considered an "ally", but in my opinion it's still not quite all the way there. Rules as written, I don't think a creature subject to *charm person* should automatically count as an ally.

However, they are friendly to you, regard you as an acquaintance, and you have advantage on social rolls. I would personally rule that you could readily attempt a quick Charisma (Persuasion or Deception) check against the subject's Wisdom (Insight) to try and convince them that they should totally let you do this magical thing to them (or that they should let your friend here cast this spell on them), and you'd get advantage against the charmed target - so you can convince them that they should consider you and your party to be allies.